# Was mathematics invented or discovered?

Tags: mathematics

Did we humans actually invent mathematics? Or did we just stumble upon this huge gift and discovered it? I read a book on this question called, "Is God A Mathematician" by Mario Livio but still couldnt ascertain the answer as the book presented the best of both ideas.

Comment: "God created the integer, rest are works of humans"

Comment: "Mathematics is the language with which God created the universe." Galileo Galilei.

Comment: This isn't a history question, it's a philosophy question.

Comment: You can see this [post](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1/was-mathematics-invented-or-discovered).

Comment: There are different opinions on this subject. The discussion continues since people started practicing mathematics. So there is no definite answer.

Comment: This question is better suited for philosophy stack exchange; however it probably is a duplicate considering that its a staple of philosophy of mathematics.

Comment: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=Mathematics+invention+discovery